# place <for me to sing at is/ that I sing at is a / where I sing is>

Tags: sentence-construction

Are the three sentences the exact same so that I can use whichever I want?

> The place ***for me to most often sing at*** is a karaoke room around my school.
>
> The place ***that I most often sing at*** is a karaoke room around my school.
>
> The place ***where I most often sing*** is a karaoke room around my school.

Comment: Please check your use of "around" - I suspect ypu mean either "at" or "near".

Comment: This is proofreading unless you add additional information or why you think there might be a problem. As it is, 1) is unnatural and wordy (why so many words?), 2) and 3) are the issue of using *that* vs. *where* which is another question. Not to mention *sing* vs. *sing at*. A better question would include details about why you are writing the examples differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of preliminaries:

- The ordinary location for *most often* in colloquial speech is after the verb:

  > ... sing at most often ...
- As Stephie says, you probably mean *near* my school; *around* in this context tends to mean *surrounding*, which doesn't make much sense.

As for your alternatives:

> The place for me to most often sing at is a karaoke room around my school.

This is unlikely. We tend to use adjectival *for* phrases like this to express an intended purpose. A karaoke room, for instance, could be "a place for people to sing at", meaning it's designed and operated with that purpose in mind. Even in this use it's pretty rare when the intended user is also the subject of the main clause. "I've found a place for my sister to sing at" is OK, but "I've found a place for me to sing at" is odd; most people would say merely "I've found a place to sing at".

> The place that I sing at most often ...
> The place where I sing most often ...

These are pretty much equivalent; relative *where* 'stands for' a preposition phrase, so it readily replaces *at which*.

But the simplest version eliminates the relative entirely:

> The place I sing most often is a karaoke room near my school.